# $\chi^2$ of $\chi^2$ as a function of a variable

Tags: chi-squared-test, goodness-of-fit, monte-carlo, fitting

I am currently measuring some unknown quantities from a discrete distribution of known quantities. This is achieved by taking a measured distribution, generating a Monte Carlo simulation of this distribution, and minimising the $\chi^2$ (Chi-Square) between data and simulation until the unknown values are measured.

Explanation:

My question relates to the nuisance parameters of the fit, which must also be calculated. These are particularly important, as the distribution is measured as a histogram and changes in the nuisance parameters result in movement of points between the bins, which consequently contribute to imperfections in the measurement of the Chi Square.

There are too many free parameters to feasibly fit in a reasonable period of time. The currently accepted solution to this in my group is the following:

1. Minimise the $\chi^2$ for whichever parameters do not require a new simulation;
2. Fix all parameters except one and calculate the $\chi^2$ between data and a new MC with a changed nuisance parameter. This is carried out as a scan $±2 \sigma$ through the parameter space.
3. Fit a 2D Polynomial to the plot of the points ($\chi^2$ vs sigmas from the last minimum) and find the minimum;
4. Set this minimum to be the new nuisance parameter;
5. Repeat 1-4 for all parameters until the minima have moved less than 0.1 $\sigma$.

Some of the parameters are very sensitive to the error on the MC, which scales as $\sqrt{N}$, and jitter at the minimum if an insufficient amount of MC data is used due to the aforementioned bin migration. However, the amount of jitter is different for each parameter: one size does not fit all. On the other hand, this process is time consuming and it is senseless to use a lot of processing time to generate an entirely new MC for a nuisance parameter that does not need it.

Question:

I must come up with a method of measuring whether this jitter is at an 'acceptable' level for a given parameter, in order to balance time and quality of fits.

My current best solution is to measure the goodness-of-fit of the 2D Polynomial on the distribution of Chi-squares vs the parameter (Measuring the Chi-square of a fit to a distribution of Chi-squares), but this is fruitless as I do not know the error on the Chi-square itself.

Is there a smarter, more elegant statistical solution that can be offered to this conundrum?

EDIT: When I say I 'generate a new MC', what I mean is that I apply different criteria to a pre-generated set of numbers and obtain a different resulting distribution.

Comment: Helping with your problem (but not answering the question): You could avoid the jitter (and improve convergence) by **not** generating new random numbers for the MC with every iteration of the steps 1-4. It would also speed up your algorithm. (I am assuming that you currently do generate these random numbers again each time, or otherwise I do not understand your jitter problem)

Comment: @MartijnWeterings Thank you, but I already do this!

The jitter arises from the fact that if I change parameters in the Monte Carlo, certain data points at the edge of a given bin may move between bins. This in turn leads to changes in the measurement of the differences between the MC bin and the Data bin, and consequently the measurement of the Chi Square.

Comment: 1) Could you explain a bit more what you do with your MC (and why). The way I understand it now is that you wish to estimate the parameters of a distribution to match some observed quantities. You do this by some gradient descent process and optimize the parameters to minimize a $\chi^2$ measure. But why (and how) do you calculate this $\chi^2$ by the use of a MC (don't the estimated values result directly from your distribution)?

Comment: 2) What do you mean by jitter around the minimum. And why do you believe it is caused by the MC, or what do you mean with it being caused by the MC? The way that I understood it at first is that the algorithm jumps around the minimum and does not converge nicely (either due to ill-posed problem, or due to, what I suspected, changing the MC with every step). Or do you mean that you get different results each time you repeat the *entire* process?

Comment: 1) The Chi square is calculated by $$\sum_{j =Bin} \frac{( N_{Data, j} - N_{MC, j})^{2}}{\sigma_{N_{Data, j}}}  $$

Comment: 2) The MC is a full distribution of random numbers which are cut by by a set of criteria. The nuisance parameters vary the criteria, and consequently different events pass the cuts depending upon the criteria applied.

Comment: So, to recapitulate, you have a function $\chi^2(\theta)$ based on nuasance parameters $\theta$ and which is non-smooth due to the calculation of $\chi^2(\theta)$ based on a MC that does not change the bin frequencies smoothly (I imagine that you could avoid the use of MC but you should provide more details about that).

Comment: .... I believe that such problem is ill-posed mostly due to the non smooth nature of the function, and not so much due to the estimate of the minimum by a polynomial. As long as you make sure that you descent in every step, then you should converge to the minimum and you don't have to worry about the polynomial fit to be appropiate or not. However, if the convergence to the global minimum is problematic because of local minima or the algorithm getting stuck in corners, then you still have a problem (which you do not solve with evaluating a chi^2 of chi^2 to improve your descent steps).

Comment: @MartijnWeterings I have function $\chi^{2}(x(\theta))$ where $\theta$ are the variables I want to measure, including nuisance parameters. There is a complicated set of machinery that dictates x($\theta$) that cannot be accounted without simulation of the experiment, since the $\theta$s are often interdependent. In answer to your question, the distribution will always be smooth given enough MC data, as proportionally fewer MC entries migrate between bins - this is the source of the jitter. The simplest and easiest solution is to simply add more MC events, but this is unsatisfactory to me.

Answer (score 2):

I have been trying to create a simple example case to clarify the situation of your problem.

For this example case I have used a logistic model
$\pi(x) = \frac{1}{1+e^{-a(x+b)}}$
with $a=1$, $b=0$ and $x = N(0,2)$

```
# model_pars
a = 1
b = 0

# x-dist_pars
xmu = 0 
xv = 2

# discretezation_pars
np = 200

# random measured data
set.seed(1)
x <- rnorm(np, xmu, xv) 
pie <- sigmoid(x, a=a, b=b)
y <- 1 * (runif(np, 0, 1) < pie)

# binning
bins = c(-4:4)/2
bsize <- length(bins) + 1

w <- sapply(x, FUN = function(x) (sum(1*(x > bins))+1))# find out bin number by counting number of smaller bins

nk0 <- sapply(1:bsize, function(i) length(which(y[which(w==i)]==0)))
nk1 <- sapply(1:bsize, function(i) length(which(y[which(w==i)]==1)))
```

resulting in the following frequency distribution

```
> nk0
 [1] 25  7 19 15 10  7  6  2  3  4
> nk1
 [1]  2  1  4  6 17  7 15 14  9 27
>
```

then using 100 times a Monte Carlo simulation (pretending that $-a(x+b)$ depends, as you mention, on complex machinery such as neural networks or whatever, and requires MC rather then direct calculation) changing the parameter $a$ and keeping fixed $b$, $\mu_x$, $\sigma_x$, results in the following graphs. The graphs in the array display the change of the single terms for the

$\chi(mc=i,bin=j) = \sqrt{\frac{(N_{Data,j}-N_{MC,i,j})^2}{N_{Data,j}}}$

*(I used $N_{data}$ for the deviations in the denominator.)*

with $i$ and $j$ varying in the columns and rows of the graph.

The larger graph in the lower left corner shows an average of the terms over different number of MC simulations.

[image: demonstration of jitter]

---

I believe it is interesting to have a graphical display of the origin of the jitter. At first I assumed that you were change the random parameters for each repetition of your Monte Carlo simulation and this would cause large variations that look like jitter. Now, the image shows that you can get this jitter from other sources as well. As you mentioned while changing the nuisance parameter causes observations to move from one bin to another. You see this in the single terms changing in steps. What is important for jitter is that you can have alternating steps up and down. While one parameter goes down another goes up. This creates jitter without a need for the single terms having jitter (if the single terms have jitter the problem becomes larger).

I wonder if jitter is really the key problem. It is more a symptom of the deviation between the MC simulations and the theoretic frequencies. It is this deviation that seems most troubling to me. See for instance the change of the curves in the figure when the number of MC simulations is increased. It is not the jitter that is so much a problem here, and it is much more the variation among different simulations.

---

Note 1:

You mention that you currently have no information about the error of the simulations ("I do not know the error on the Chi-square itself"). Does this mean that you perform only a single simulation (with varying nuisance parameter)? You don't have multiple $N_{MC}$ for fixed nuisance that allows you to estimate variation of your $\chi$ parameter and terms for each bin and $\chi^2$?

How much trouble would it be to perform the scan with lower accuracy and use the gain in computation time to perform multiple simulations in order to estimate the variation between different simulations at the same point in the parameter space?

Maybe I am getting something incorrect. Could you better describe your Monte Carlo simulation? Number of simulations, change of parameters and random numbers, etc. Add some graphs.

---

Note 2:

Another note. You may get more jitter when changing particular parameters. But, eventually the error of the MC simulation is, around the same point, the same for all parameters (and it is just that the simulation error manifests in more or less jitter depending on the parameter that is being scanned).